# Display my SUM () appears on on Linq

Tags: linq

I'm working right now to display the SUM to my LINQ but it will in no way apparent as it makes mistakes.

I've done like this

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

var brugerPoint = db.brugeres.Sum();
    if (brugerPoint != null)
    {
        LiteralBrugere.Text = "<strong data-to='" + brugerPoint.ToString() + "'>" + brugerPoint.ToString() + "</strong>";
    }
```

EIDT i have try its here:

```
var brugerPointVB = db.brugeres.Where(brugerPoint => brugerPoint.point >= 0).Sum();
    if (brugerPointVB != null)
    {
        LiteralBrugere.Text = "<strong data-to='" + brugerPointVB.ToString() + "'>" + brugerPointVB.ToString() + "</strong>";
    }
```

after i have look her: [c# / Linq sum where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561312/c-sharp-linq-sum-where)

EIDT EIDT NEW

```
var brugerPointAAA = db.brugeres.Sum(brugerPoint => brugerPoint.point);
    if (brugerPointAAA != null)
    {
        LiteralBrugere.Text = "<strong data-to='" + brugerPointAAA.ToString() + "'>" + brugerPointAAA.ToString() + "</strong>";
    }
```

Comment: What are you summing?  I'm assuming `brugeres` is a table and not a collection of values.

Comment: @DStanley `brugeres` is the name of the lost where my users come from,

Comment: I think you mean it throws exceptions. Which?

Comment: @GertArnold What you mean on this you say?

Comment: You need to tell `Sum` which field (or expression) you are summing - something like `.Sum(b => b.Price)`. (replacing `Price` with the field you are summing)

Comment: @DStanley I add a new bit, is this what you mean?

Comment: @JesperPetersen if `point` is the field you're summing than that looks reasonable.  What errors/bad results do you get with that method?

Comment: @DStanley I get nothing back at all. :(

Comment: `Sum` returns an `int` which can never be null, so your line `if burgerPointAAA != null` doesn't make any sense.